# Alias from nested use statement inside __using__

Tags: elixir

So let's say that I have a module `App.A` that has the following code

```
defmodule App.A do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      alias App.B
    end
  end
end
```

so when it is `used` it automatically adds an alias for `App.B`.

Now, there is another module called `App.C` defined like this:

```
defmodule App.C do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      use App.A

      def foo do
        B.bar()
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which adds a function `foo` which tries to call a function from the module `B` without explicitly
aliasing it because I would expect that using `App.A` will already define an alias.

Now, the problem is that when I have some other module, say `App.D` which `uses` `App.C`,
compilation will give me a warning saying that B is undefined so that alias didn't work.

Could somebody explain please why it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are local to the scope in which they are used. The `quote` block of the `__using__` macro is executed in the function of the calling module, therefore the alias is valid. However when calling `use App.C` - the alias is not in that scope, so calling B.bar() will fail.

You can validate this by changing `App.C` to:

```
defmodule App.C do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      use App.A

      IO.inspect B == App.B # false
      alias App.B
      IO.inspect B == App.B # true

      def foo do
        B.bar()
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You'll notice that as long as the alias is present in c.ex, it will work. You can define it anywhere in the file before it is used:

```
alias App.B
defmodule App.C do
  # alias App.B
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    # alias App.B
    quote do
      use App.A 
      # alias App.B

      def foo do
       # alias App.B
        B.bar()
      end
    end
  end
end
```